# How to generate SSLCertificateChainFile,SSLCertificateFile,SSLCertificateKeyFile?

Tags: apache, ssl-certificate, centos7

I generated SSL Certificate under /etc/httpd/conf using the following command

openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout apache.key -out apache.crt

How to generate SSLCertificateChainFile and SSLCipherSuite?
What is needed after generating?

Comment: I'm surprised this question is here after 4+ years. Typically you get the `SSLCertificateChainFile ` from your certificate authority eg. GoDaddy or other.